# How access values from JSON model

Tags: c#, json, oop, switch-statement

In this code here I set the values to model classes from `JSON` file called `myJson`.code works fine and values binding to the model classes without any issues. My code as follows.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ReadJson();
    }

    public static string ReadJson()
    {
        string case20 = "this is 20", case40 = "this is 40";
        string json;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Output\myJson.json"))
        {
            json = r.ReadToEnd();
        }
        MyClass response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
        var dropDowns = response;
        string jsonDropdown = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dropDowns, Formatting.Indented);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Here is my model classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int RATE { get; set; }
    public int FEE { get; set; }
    public int PERIOD { get; set; }

    public string NewValue
    {
        get
        {
            var rateVal = this.RATE;
            switch (rateVal)
            {
                case 20:
                    return ""; // Here, I need to get value from the ReadJson method to return (value of case20)
                case 40:
                    return ""; // Here, I need to get value from the ReadJson method to return (value of case40)
            }
            return "test";
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public object LoanDetail { get; set; }
}
```

After I set the values to model classes,from the `Customer` class I want to check the `RATE` and in order to the value of the `RATE` I want to return value of the `case20` and `case40` variable's value in the `ReadJson()` method. How can I access those value form `Customer` class.

Thanks in advance!!!

**Updated:**

This is sample `JSON` string

```
{
   "StatusCode": "100",
   "Customer": {
      "RATE": 20,
      "FEE": 3000,
      "PERIOD": 60,
      "NewValue":""
   },
   "LoanDetail": null
}
```

According to belove JSON string, My output should be

```
{
   "StatusCode": "100",
   "Customer": {
      "RATE": 20,
      "FEE": 3000,
      "PERIOD": 60,
      "NewValue":"this is 20"
   },
   "LoanDetail": null
}
```

Comment: How looks like your json structure?

Comment: @Emre I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped me to solve this. I found the solution to solve my problem.

I created a static class, called `TestCase`.

```
public static class TestCase
{
    public static string case20 { get; set; }
    public static string case40 { get; set; }
}
```

Then set the values to those fields within the `ReadJson()`

```
public static string ReadJson()
{
    TestCase.case20 = "this is 20";
    TestCase case40 = "this is 40";
    // same code has beign used....
}
```

Then within the `Customer` class, I accessed those values as follows.

```
public class Customer

{
    public int RATE { get; set; }
    public int FEE { get; set; }
    public int PERIOD { get; set; }

    public string NewValue
    {
        get
        {
            switch (RATE)
            {
                case 20:
                    return TestCase.case20;
                case 40:
                    return TestCase.case40;
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's how I would have done it for a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are reading the JSON data from the string into your customer object.

Shouldn't the case20 & case40 be set in the customer object or program themselves?

You are not reading into the case20 or 40 strings from the JSON anywhere I could see. So I am assuming that their output does not change dynamically when running the program.

Also your `var rateVale = this.rate;` should be something like `var rateVal = int.Parse(this.rate);` as you are comparing it as an integer. either that or switch cases should be "20" not 20 etc.

Can you include an example of the code you have and what the appropriate object values should be and the output of the newValue parameter please?

Comment: I check the `Rate` value from JSON and based on that value I need to set the values to `NewValue`. And updated the question and my JSON as above

Comment: Thank for your answer, I solved my problem and I posted it :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change your code according below and it does what you want. But I still cant understand why you need NewValue property while you have already RATE property. Does not they carrying same value? You setting NewValue based on RATE, why dont you use just RATE everywhere?

```
    public static string ReadJson()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Output\myJson.json");

        MyClass response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
    }

public class Customer

{
    public int RATE { get; set; }
    public int FEE { get; set; }
    public int PERIOD { get; set; }

    public string NewValue
    {
        get
        {
            switch (RATE)
            {
                case 20:
                    return "this is 20";
                case 40:
                    return "this is 40";
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(ReadJson());
    }
```

The output is :

```
{
  "StatusCode": "100",
  "Customer": {
    "RATE": 20,
    "FEE": 3000,
    "PERIOD": 60,
    "NewValue": "this is 20"
  },
  "LoanDetail": null
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I solved my problem and I posted it :) Thanks again